# Liking a facebook page from wordpress website?

Tags: php, css, facebook

I have added a button that links to a facebook page at the left of my [**website**](http://mamou-mani.com), I would like to be able to let people like the page directly from my website. How can I do that?

Right now I added the following CSS line:

```
#fbtab{
background: url(http://mamou-mani.com/wp-content/themes/arthur/images/icon-fbtab.png) no-repeat; /* Path to Image */
left:1px;  /* change this to left: 1px; to put it on the left of the screen */
top:40%;height:60px;width:60px;margin:0px;padding:0;position:fixed;z-index:5000;}
#fbtab a{display:block;width:100%;height:100%;}
```

and following line in my footer.php:

```
<p id="fbtab"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MamouManiArch"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** 
To get floating social icons, including facebook 'like', try [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-facebook-google-plusone-share/) plugin.****

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I place the widget on the left side of my [website](http://mamou-mani.com), like the sign I already have?

Comment: Follow the other answer above and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi Aliyah, which code are we talking about? the widget's code?

Comment: Thanks but the link is not working

Comment: My fault, check the link again. Or, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-facebook-google-plusone-share/

Comment: Thanks Aliyah, I've tried this plugin in the past but the problem is placing the button at the right location. This is really the difficult part.

Comment: You want it where that "F" button currently appears?

Comment: yes :) I might need to redesign the f circle but for now just replacing it with a like button would do. Thanks

Comment: I see. Hold on while I look for a solution

Comment: Taking longer than expected. I'll try to come up with something tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

And setup a facebook like button without the send option.

Comment: Thanks but where do I place this? in my CSS or footer.php?

Comment: What you want to do is copy the "src" part and paste it within your footer.

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately it did not work. I have placed the following code in my footer: `<p id="fbtab"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MamouManiArch"><src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMAMOUMANIARCH&amp;width=300&amp;height=260&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=on&amp;border_color=%23ddd&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false">
</a></p>`

Comment: Try the plugin I linked to in my answer

Comment: Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

And setup a facebook like button without the send option.